# Generic list in java to hold any objects

Tags: java, list, generics

I am new to Java.
I want to make an array List which will be able to hold any objects.
I am wondering how to achie this. I am trying to use Class, but I am not sure how do I get the  object from that. Here is what I am tring to do

```
<T> List<T> ConvertToList(<Map <String, List<Long>>map, Class<T> clazz)
{
//I want to extract all values from the map and store into an object as refered
//by clazz and put that into list.

...
...
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Is it possible and if yes how to do that?

Comment: That isn't valid java code.  It is not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish...  What is a "<map"?

Comment: Do you want to convert Map's values to List ?

Comment: so you want to put values present in Map in an object which is of type "clazz" and then put that object in your arraylist ?

Comment: @Sikorski: Yes exactly.

Comment: ok, any idea what this class could be and what does it look like i mean its java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `List` implementation *can* hold any type of `Object`. This is because it employs generics. Keep in mind that an `ArrayList` is only a wrapper for an `array` of elements. It simply *appears* to manipulate the size of that array by redeclaring it behind the scenes. It's simple enough to replicate this functionality, as below:

```
public class MyList<T> {
    T[] elements;
}
```

This can be initialised in a number of ways:

```
MyList<String> list = new MyList<String>();

MyList<MyList<Integer>> intList = new MyList<MyList<Integer>>();
```

And so, by definition, you can expose it as the raw type:

```
MyList myObjectList = new MyList();
```

But your IDE will complain, and this is a good thing. You should avoid dealing with the type `Object`, and try to make it more specific, to avoid casting things all over the place.

**Example - Writing a method signature to convert a `Map` implementation to a `List` implementation.**

This one is a little more interesting, but follows the same principle. Let's say you want to create a single list from all the `values` in a `Map`.

```
public List<T> <K,T> mapToList(Map<K, T> map) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    list.addAll(map.values());

    return list;
}
```

**NOTE**: This was included so you can get a better idea of how generics work, and how Java deals with variable method arguments.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote, considering OP was happy enough to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question is yes. To do this, use the following code

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can now add class that extends Object to the array list, I believe all classes do this implicitly.